# Material date picker selected date circle is out of center ,How to make it fit center?

Tags: android, android-studio, material-design, material-components-android, android-datepicker

[image: link to screenshot]

This is style i have used for material Calendar separately, everything is perfect except selected date circle

```
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/colorAppBackground</item>
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextAppearance">@style/RobotoMenuText</item>
    <item name="titleTextAppearance">@style/RobotoMenuText</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/RobotoMenuText</item>
    <item name="colorSurface">@color/colorAppGreen</item>
    <item name="materialCalendarTheme">@style/CalenderTheme</item>
    <item name="materialCalendarFullscreenTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar.Fullscreen</item>
    <item name="materialCalendarStyle">@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar</item>
</style>
<style name="CalenderTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/colorAppBackground</item>
</style>
```

Comment: hey PC mail, can you tell me which library are you using  ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You [have to switch](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md#4-change-your-app-theme-to-inherit-from-a-material-components-theme) from the `Theme.AppCompat` to a `Theme.MaterialComponents` or a `Bridge` Theme.

Use:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar.Bridge">
    <!-- ...... -->
    <item name="materialCalendarStyle">@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar</item>
    <item name="materialCalendarFullscreenTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar.Fullscreen</item>
    <item name="materialCalendarTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar</item>
</style>
```

Comment: I changed the theme but still does not work

Comment: This does not help.